# $z: |z| + |z-z_0| = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

Exercise 23 (page 15) in Golan - The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know (3rd edition).

> Let $0 \neq z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy the condition $|z_0| < 2$. Show that there are precisely two complex numbers, $z_1$ and $z_2$, satisfying $|z_1| + |z_2| = 1$ and $z_1 + z_2 = z_0$.

Well.. ok so $z_2 = z_0 - z_1$ and let me set $z = z_1$ which is my real unknown. I need to find all the $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| + |z-z_0| = 1$.

The problem is that $|z| + |z-z_0| \geq |z_0|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
So if $|z_0|>1$ it seems to me that the problem has no solutions at all.
Also, if $|z_0|\leq1$, it seems to me that there are an infinity of solutions, not two.

What am I missing?

Comment: So, the sum of the distances from $z$ to two different points ($0$ and $z_0$) is a constant. Smells like an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Definition_as_locus_of_points).

Comment: It is indeed an ellipse with two foci $0$ and $z_0$ when $|z_0|<1$. It degenerates to a line segment joining $0$ and $z_0$ if $|z_0|=1$. I suspect that the problem is asking the number of *real* solutions in the case of $|z_0|<1$.

Comment: Suppose $z_0$ is real. Otherwise use a rotation $e^{i\phi}$ to make it real. Then $|e^{i\phi}z_0| = |z_0|$ and you can rotate the solutions back in the end. Now this implies that $\mathcal{Im}(z_1) = - \mathcal{Im}(z_2)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @SangchulLee so you agree that the problem as stated cannot be right?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks!